# Error in ./src/styles.less when upgrading from Angular 9 to 10

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, less, angular10

Im upgrading angular from 9 to 10, and when i run ng build I this error.

> ERROR in ./src/styles.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??--14-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_mdules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??--14-3!./src/styles.less)
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):
>
> .make-grid(xs);
> ^
> Maximum call stack size exceeded
> Error in C:...\node_modules\bootstrap\less\grid.less (line 56, column 0)
> Error:
>
> .make-grid(xs);
> ^
> Maximum call stack size exceeded
> Error in C:...\node_modules\bootstrap\less\grid.less (line 56, column 0)
> at C:...\node_modules\less-loader\dist\index.js:62:14
> @ ./src/styles.less 2:26-207
> multi ./src/styles.less

Im using node 12.11.0

I think it is related to some of the imported styles inside the styles.less but with angular 9 it works fine, I don't know what could change about those styles with angular 10.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: "Im using node 12.11.0" — Well, don't. It went past [end of life](https://github.com/nodejs/release#release-schedule) over a year ago. Use a supported version of Node.

Comment: Im using that version because it is the newest for Angular 10 https://angular.io/guide/versions